# 'Target is not a directory'when copying single file to multiple destinations

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm trying to copy a single file (a picture of Nicholas Cage, don't ask) so that it replaces a whole folder full of phpBB user avatars (It's almost April the 1st!). However, I get this response:

```
joe@yada:~/upload$ for i in "ls *"; do cp ~/cage.jpg $i; done
cp: target `0e88f82965461cc1b418ddfda60935c8_99.jpg' is not a directory
```

How can I tell cp that in this instance, everything is a file?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please elaborate it?Do you want to replace every file in a directory with ~/cage.jpg?

Comment: Further reading: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

You're using incorrect syntax. The following command

```
for i in "ls *"
```

uses bash wild card expansion, transforming the actual string into

```
for i in "ls file1 file2 dir1 so_on 0e88f82965461cc1b418ddfda60935c8_99.jpg"
```

and that string value is assigned to `i`

Next cp tries to execute

```
cp ~/cage.jpg ls file1 file2 dir1 so_on 0e88f82965461cc1b418ddfda60935c8_99.jpg
```

and before checking if any of the input files are invalid, it checks if the destination is a directory, which it isn't, hence the error.

To correct it, change `"ls *"` to `$(ls *)`, or better yet just `*` to avoid needless subshell call

Comment: I managed it in the end, I replaced 'ls *' with simply '/home/joe/upload/*'. That worked first time.